# Вывод данных

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть таблица. Выглядит она так.

```
  `user_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_group` datetime NOT NULL,
  `del_user1` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `del_user2` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

И сам вывод.

```
<?
$get_con = $bd->query("SELECT u.id,p.hash,p.user_one,p.user_two,p.date_group,
 u.username,u.family,u.avatarthb,u.lastdate,u.olddate
 FROM message_group p INNER JOIN users u
 ON CASE
 WHEN p.user_one = '$myrow2[id]'
 THEN p.user_two = u.id
 WHEN u.id != '$myrow[id]'
 THEN p.user_one= u.id
 END
 AND (
p.user_one ='$myrow2[id]'
OR p.user_two ='$myrow[id]'
)
Order by p.date_group DESC Limit 15") or die(mysql_error());
?>
Вот не могу  сделать выборку del_user1 и del_user2 помогите пожалуйста.
```

Comment: `u.del_user1, u.del_user2` добавить в `SELECT` не канает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$get_con = $bd->query("SELECT u.id,p.hash,p.user_one,p.user_two,p.date_group,
 u.username,u.family,u.avatarthb,u.lastdate,u.olddate,p.del_user1,p.del_user2
FROM message_group p INNER JOIN users u
 ON CASE
 WHEN p.user_one = '$myrow2[id]'
 THEN p.user_two = u.id
 WHEN u.id != '$myrow[id]'
 THEN p.user_one= u.id
 END
 AND (
p.user_one ='$myrow2[id]'
OR p.user_two ='$myrow[id]'
)
AND (
p.del_user1 =0
OR p.del_user2 =0
)
Order by p.date_group DESC Limit 15") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @yarnik Простите просто дописать забыл.Смотрите у меня del_user1 или del_user2 равняется с начало 0, а при клике типа удалить делается упдейт на 1.Вот мне нужно вывести del_user1 и del_user2 где равняется он 0.

Comment: отредактировал, теперь будет показывать где есть хотя бы один 0

Comment: @yarnik Спасибо большое.